# Reading data from excel sheet in c#, loading data into a strings for each column in a row

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable

I am working on reading data from excel sheet. My table will look like this.

```
        AAAA            bbbbb              cccc
        1                2                  3
        4                5                  6
        --------------------------------------



        --------------------------------------

       data           data                  data
```

I want to loop though each and every row and save each value at each cell in a seperate string.

Here as per my table,

I want to store,

```
    string column1= 1;
    string cloumn2=2;
    string clomnn3= 3;
```

I want to repeat this for all rows. My excel will have only three columns.

I have tried this code

```
        //Reading Excel file
        string datafilename = @"D:\Book2.xls";
        string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + datafilename + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"; 
        OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", strConn);
        //fetching excel data into DataTable 
        System.Data.DataTable _dtDataFile = new System.Data.DataTable();
        ArrayList abcd = new ArrayList();
        myCommand.Fill(_dtDataFile);

        foreach (DataRow row in _dtDataFile.Rows)
        {
            Response.Write(row[i]);

        }
```

The output i got is

```
    12346............datadatadata
```

I am getting all data in a single string, i want to store data in seperate strings for each row.

Can any one suggest, how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: `Response.Write(row[i].ToString()+"<br/>");`?

Comment: Your code isn't complete. Where did you get that `i` var?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? A DataTable stores already all fields in separate variables, why do you need to create a duplicate in whatever type of collection?

Comment: What's the point of the ArrayList `abcd` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting all your data in one string because you're writing it all straight to the response stream. You need to either add markup as Arion suggested, or actually add these values to some data structure. Also, have you thought about using the [Excel Object Library](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)? It might be a bit cleaner, plus you can iterate the native structure of the file directly.